# How would you describe the movement of a lever?

Tags: verbs, american-english, british-english, collocation

The story is that I was describing an action happens in the car park in class, and I got stuck, I said something like: "after putting a coin in the slot of the parking meter, then the lever would be elevated automatically." I still don't know which verb should I use; I've got a couple of candidates - raise, lift, elevate. 
Which verb could be the best one? Or none of them is correct hh??

Comment: Do you mean the barrier? Levers are usually moved by people, mainly using their hands.

Comment: @Keep these mind I think my account was quite ambiguous; it's like in a car park, there's a lever which serves as a barrier, I'm talking about that and wanting to know the verb lol!

Comment: @Michael Harvey so those barriers are not moved automatically? As in China they are electronically controlled so I asked that question; but if they're moved by hands, what kind of verb can I use, say, to lift the barrier?

Comment: In that case: opened

Comment: The poles, often with with stripes, that can rise and fall to allow or block the passage of vehicles, are not called 'levers'. They can be called barriers or poles. Usually they are raised or lowered by an electric motor, which could be controlled by a human (an attendant or guard), or by a coin-in-the-slot machine.

Comment: "The barrier opened" or "The barrier was raised" or "The barrier went up"

Comment: Raised, lifted, flipped upward, et  al.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Now I see, I didn't even know how should I call that, thus i called it a lever hhh

Answer (score 1):

"Elevated" or "raised"

> After you put a coin in the slot, the barrier would be elevated automatically.
>
> After you put a coin in the slot, the barrier would be raised automatically.

Technically the device can indeed be considered a lever, since there is a pivot inside the machine and a mechanism that moves part of the bar a small distance so that the long part of the bar moves a long distance. However most people would call it a barrier rather than a lever, because - from their point of view as end-users - the role of the pole is to bar entry to the car park, rather than to help them move something.

[image]

Comment: In fact many people I know just call it "the bar"  and the bar goes up and comes down.  "Wait for the bar to go up before pulling forward"  and "He tried to sneak in on the tail of the car in front of him, but the bar came down on the root of his car."